# unable to deploy symfony project to a shared hosting web server

Tags: php, symfony1, webdeploy

i am using Symfony 1.4, to create my project. i have tried to deploy project using the command and methods given in chapter-16 in symfony book. but i am not able to deploy my symfony project from my local computer to web server. Can i directly copy paste my symfony project to my web server?? will that work?? or is there any other method?? 
NOTE: i am using Propel as ORM.

Comment: we installed a fresh symfony project in our web server, and planning to build project there itself and transfer our code form local server to web server.

Comment: symfony's documentation is not good enough..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option is:
1.  gzip up the entire project
2.  export all the data from the database using something like mysqldump
3.  upload the files to the server
4.  import the database dump into your server database
5.  unzip your project

A couple notes:
1.  Due to the shared hosting environment, you may have security issues due to other hosts on the server gaining access to your php files See [here](http://trac.symfony-project.org/wiki/SymfonyPHPsuexec).
2.  Hopefully your host allows SSH access to your server account, administering a symfony project is MUCH easier when this is the case.
3.  If you don't have SSH access to your account you will have to upload the files to the server without gzipping them and this takes a LONG time due to the number of files symfony creates.
4.  If possible place all your symfony files except for the web folder outside the public_html folder.

Comment: how can we, make web folder accessible outside the symfony file structure...because we also installed symfony on our web server, and then called the controller file directly, but it showed 404!

Comment: @Harish Kurup you should use a symlink  ln -s /path/to/dest /path/to/source

Answer (score 0):

When I have to deploy something I do this:

Check if the requirement (php5, mysql4 etc) on the production server matches my application.
Change the configuration files to reflect the production server.
Upload everything to the server using ftp.

Your question is cryptic, you should really specify what kind of error you are getting.

Comment: actually the commands like "php symfony project:deploy -t –go" were not working as they said in documentation.